# Entender mensagem de erro

Tags: java

Não estou conseguindo entender essa mensagem de erro. Alguém entende e pode me ajudar?

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210)
> at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
> at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:261)
> at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:235)
> at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:227)
> at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:458)
> at so.SO.main(SO.java:100)
> ```

Meu código

```
try {

        try (FileReader arq = new FileReader(arquivo)) {
            BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);

            String linha = lerArq.readLine();

            num_processos = Integer.parseInt(linha);

            String array[] = new String[3];  // array criado para determinar a quantidade de parÃ£metros a serem armazenados.

            while (linha != null) {         // CondiÃ§Ã£o de saÃ­da do arquivo pois quando acabam as linhas o valor Ã© null.

                linha = lerArq.readLine();

                if (linha != null) //CondiÃ§Ã£o usada para verificar se estÃ¡ em uma linha vazia uma vez que somente o while ainda dava alguns erros.
                {
                    quantidade_linha++; // Contador de linhas do arquivo "txt".

                    cont_caracter = 0;  // Contador de caracteres.

                    if (quantidade_linha == 2) {
                        num_ciclos = Integer.parseInt(linha);

                    }

                    if (quantidade_linha > 2) {
                        PID++;
                        temporario = new Processos();  // instanciamento do processo temporÃ¡rio para que a cada linha seja registrado um novo.
                        temporario.inicializa(PID);   // MÃ©todo contido na classe de Processos para inicializar com "0" os valores do mesmo.

                        while (cont_caracter < linha.length()) {      // CondiÃ§Ã£o para chegada ao fim da linha.

                            array = linha.split(",");           // Caracter usado para separamento usando o mÃ©todo split.

                            // Atribuir os valores ao processo temporÃ¡rio.
                            temporario.num_ciclos = (Integer.parseInt(array[0]));
                            temporario.entrada_saida = (Integer.parseInt(array[1]));
                            temporario.prioridade = (Integer.parseInt(array[2]));

                            cont_caracter++;
                        }
                        // CondiÃ§Ã£o para determinar em qual lista o processo entratrÃ¡ dependendo da sua prioridade.
                        if (temporario.prioridade == 0) {
                            prioridade0.add(temporario);
                        } else if (temporario.prioridade == 1) {
                            prioridade1.add(temporario);
                        } else if (temporario.prioridade == 2) {
                            prioridade2.add(temporario);
                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }

            }

            while (!fim) {
                for (i = 0; i < prioridade2.size(); i++) {
                    while (prioridade2.get(i).num_ciclos > 0) {
                        pronto.add(prioridade2.get(i));
                    }
                }
                for (i = 0; i < prioridade1.size(); i++) {
                    while (prioridade1.get(i).num_ciclos > 0) {
                        pronto.add(prioridade1.get(i));
                    }
                }
                for (i = 0; i < prioridade0.size(); i++) {
                    while (prioridade0.get(i).num_ciclos > 0) {
                        pronto.add(prioridade0.get(i));
                    }
                }

                fim = true;
            }
            System.out.println("FIM DA EXECUÇÃO!");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.err.printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo: %s.\n",
                e.getMessage());

    }
```

Comment: Adicione o código que está disparando este erro na pergunta tambem, clicando em EDITAR.

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError` significa que você tentou usar mais memória do que a máquina virtual do Java aguenta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Heap

*Heap* é o lugar (espaço na memória) onde os objetos criados em Java são alocados.

Na *heap* são alocados apenas objetos. Métodos e outras paradas são armazenadas em outro lugar.

A *heap* é dividida em duas regiões: *Nursery* e *Old Space*.

- **Nursery**: Região onde são alocados os objetos novos
- **Old Space**: Região onde são alocados objetos que já têm algum tempo de vida

---

### Como funciona?

Quando a *Nursery* começa a encher, é feita uma espécie de "transição" de objetos entre uma região e a outra. Essa transição é chamada de *Young Collection*, onde os objetos alocados inicialmente na *Nursery* (que já estão com algum tempo de vida) vão para a região *Old Space*.

Quando a região *Old Space* começa a encher, é feita uma coleta chamada *Old Collection*, onde os objetos "velhos" começam a ser de fato removidos da memória.

---

### `OutOfMemoryError`

> Não estou conseguindo entender essa mensagem de erro. Alguém entende e pode me ajudar?

Essa mensagem informa que todo o espaço na *Heap* foi utilizado. O *Garbage Collector* não conseguiu liberar a quantidade de memória necessária para a continuidade da execução da aplicação a tempo.

Não é mais possível mover objetos da *Nursery* para a *Old Space* nem remover da *Old Space*

---

### Como resolver?

Isso é diretamente relacionado á sua implementação.

Não foi postado nenhum código, dessa forma a galera o SOpt não pode lhe ajudar a fazer uma implementação melhor/menos "custosa".

Poste seu código para que possamos ajudar.

---

### Cenários comuns de `OutOfMemoryError`

Estes são alguns cenários comuns onde pode-se ocorrer `OutOfMemoryError`:

- Laços de repetição que criam muitos objetos novos
- Ler e/ou escrever em arquivos armazenando muita informação em memória
- Trazer muita informação do banco (paginação "burra" é um exemplo)
- Manter referências á objetos desnecessariamente

Dentre várias outras possibilidades.

---

Referências: [*Heap*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html) e [`OutOfMemoryError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html)

Comment: Editei colocando meu código..

Comment: É o segundo tópico que comentei (ler arquivo na memória). Perceba que você adiciona a variável `temporario` nas listas e usa essas listas até mesmo fora do loop. Isso faz com que as referências a todas instâncias de `Processo` criadas sejam válidas fora do loop, fazendo com que o _Garbage Collector_ não consiga limpar a memória, pois para ele, todas essas instâncias ainda estão "em uso".

Answer (score 6):

Isso ocorre, pois a configuração padrão da JVM (caso você não tenha alterado nenhum parâmetro na instalação) gira em torno de 16 MB.

Porem não há como lhe dar uma resposta conclusiva pois não sei o que levou seu aplicativo a usar todo o espaço alocado de memória, você pode estar executando um laço infinito, preenchendo um vetor buffer, entre tantas outras opções, caso sua aplicação seja realmente grande e utilize maior quantidade de memória, você pode reconfigurar esse volume na sua JVM.

Para reconfigurar o volume de memória utilizado pela JVM em tempo de execução temos dois comandos:

- **-Xms**: que define a quantidade **mínima** de memória Heap para a JVM;
- **-Xmx**: que define a quantidade **máxima** de memória Heap para a JVM.

Podemos usar para executar:
`Java –Xms256M –Xmx1024M –jar seuApp.jar`

Link sobre configuração de memória na JVM, muito bem explicativo por sinal  do [luizricardo.org](http://luizricardo.org/2014/11/entendendo-as-configuracoes-de-memoria-da-maquina-virtual-java-jvm/)

Caso utilize NetBeans pode alterar esses valores através das Propriedades do Projeto, em Construir > Executar > Opções de VM